# Is there a way to render multiple characters as one glyph in a true type font?

Tags: unicode, truetype, glyph

I am looking for a way to render several characters (e.g. the sequence `tlh`) as one glyph in a true type font. This should not simply leave out the `l` and `h` in the font, as the standalone characters `l` or `h` have their own appearance in the Klingon writing system.

This rendering is required for displaying Latin transcriptions of Klingon texts. Klingon characters are transcripted in Latin the following way.

```
a b ch D e gh H I j l m n ng o p q Q r S t tlh u v w y ʼ
```

**I am hence looking for a way to render the characters `ch`, `gh`, `ng` and `tlh` as their Klingon equivalent without losing the ability to render standalone `n`, `t`, `l` or.**

**Is this somehow possible in a true type font? Or would you recommend any other font type?**

Up to now, usually a transcription is used for Latin rendering which is known as `xifan hol`, where the *longer* characters are simply replaced by single characters like `tlh`→ `x` or `ng` → `f`. I would like to avoid this workaround

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [*ligatures*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_ligature)?

Comment: Glyphs and characters are independent entities. You can choose the mapping (also with multiple characters).

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know the name of the feature `ligature` nor about its existence. I reached at creating my Klingon font using FontForge.